# Why can't my call to printf() display the right characters in console?

Tags: c, string, printf, const-char

In visual studio, I can clearly see that the `rstr()` (to reverse string) function returns "olla\0", but the console display shows unreadable character symbols. Also, for some reason, after the call to `printf()`, the variable `reverse` transforms into unreadable character values too while watching variables in debug mode. Does anyone know how to correctly display the string returned by `rstr()`?

```
#include "stdio.h"

const char* rstr(const char* message) {

    const int msg_size = sizeof(message) / sizeof(message[0]);
    char r[msg_size + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < msg_size; ++i) {
        r[i] = message[msg_size - i - 1];
        if (i == (msg_size - 1))
            r[msg_size] = '\0';
    }

    return r;
}

int main() 
{
    const char* reversed = rstr("allo");
    printf("Reversed string is: %s\n", reversed);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `r` is locally-scoped.  Once you return from that function, it loses scope and the data is garbage.  Use `malloc` to allocate space on the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const int msg_size = sizeof(message) / sizeof(message[0]);
```

is all wrong here.

message is a `char*`, so `sizeof(message)` will be the size of a pointer to char.

And since `message[0]` is a char, `sizeof(message[0])` is one by definition. So your `msg_size` will be the size of a pointer to char.

You need to pass the length of the String into your `rstr()` function.